# unable to retrieve location - MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, coordinates

I have the following code:

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
self.mapView.delegate = self;
[self.mapView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
```

The blue dot with my current location shows up, but when I try to log it to the console it gives me nothing.

```
NSLog(@"%f", self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude);
```

This should be really simple, so where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the location is gottten in an async way so logging it right away won't get you anything.

you have to wait for the delegate call 'mapView:didupdateUserLocation'

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation`

only then is the value valid

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! But what I'm struggling with is the I have an url request. I want part of the request to contain the lat and lng. Should I just move the entire thing in the delegate function you're referring to?

Comment: well don't post it before getting the data so I would move it to a private `doMyPost` method and have the delegate call that